# Updating the value of a dictionary which is itself the value of another dictionary

Tags: c#

I'm working on an application where I want to use a Dictionary in another one (I may have done this with a custom object, but I never used Dictionary so I want to give it a try).
I actually got a Dictionary like this :

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>
```

Later, I'll refer to the first key as "reference", to the second as "name" and to the double as "quantity".

Here's what I want to do with this :

```
if the first Dictionary contain key reference
    if the value of key reference contain the key name
        add to the value of key name quantity
    if there isn't
        add to the value of key reference a Dictionary which as name as key and quantity as value
if there isn't
    add reference as a key and as value a second Dictionary which as name as key and quantity as value
```

Here's what I actually have :

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>> firstDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>();
Dictionary<string, double> buffer = new Dictionary<string, double>();

string reference;
string name;
double quantity;

SQLDataReader reader = myQuery.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())
{
    reference = reader["reference"].ToString();
    name = reader["name"].ToString();
    quantity = Convert.ToDouble(reader["quantity"].ToString().Replace(".", ","));

    if (firstDictionary.ContainsKey(reference))
    {
        if(firstDictionary[reference].ContainsKey(name))
        {
            firstDictionary[reference][name] += quantity;
        }
        else 
        {
            firstDictionary[reference][name] = quantity;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        buffer.Clear();
        buffer.Add(name, quantity);
        firstDictionary[reference] = buffer;                            
    }
}
```

But I got a problem with this. My query return is what I expect so there's no problem with that, but my Dictionary isn't.
All references are like they should, but every names and quantities are the same. It looks like all name are changed when I add a new one and all quantity are set to the same value when I try to update one. Given that, I tried to change some few things, but nothing changed.
I guess it's because of the Dictionary in another Dictionary so :
**Is it possible to do want I want to with Dictionary ?** (I know it's not the best solution anyway)
**If so, could anyone help me out with this ?** Even just a hint would be appreciated here.

Comment: I think you shouldn't do that with dictionary, maybe it is better to do with a custom object

Comment: As suggested try to use custom object. But if you still want to use dictionary you need to instantiate a new one in every iteration, this will solve your problem.

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim I know that, but as I have written above, I never used Dictionary, so I'd like to use it (even if it isn't the best solution) to see how it actually works and how i may use it for later use. But if I **can't** use it to do what I want, then I'm gonna use an object.

Comment: If you wanted to nest the results you could have used a LINQ query with a `GroupBy`. Even better, write a SQL query that returns what you want in a single operation.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do with the last `else` clause. If the idea is to add the not found reference to your original dictionary, you'd have to do something like `firstDictionary[reference] = new Dictionary<string,double>() { { name, quantity }}`

Comment: @MatthieuFoltzer Dictionary works. That's not what's wrong here, it's the code. There's no reason to use strings or decimal replacements when working with numbers for example. The line `Convert.ToDouble(reader["quantity"].ToString().Replace(".", ","))` can *only* return the original value or bad data. If `quantity` is a double, just write `(double)reader["quantity"]`. It it's a string, a) why? and b) `ToString()` is a no-op and instead of trying to replace commas, you should pass the correct CultureInfo to `Convert` or better yet, `double.Parse()`

Comment: You probably should combine the keys into a single object (e.g. a `Tuple`) and use that as key. That way you shouldn't have any problems to add all your items into a single `Dictionary` and have access to any of them with the same info you got now.

Comment: @MatthieuFoltzer `My query return is what I expect so there's no problem with that, but my Dictionary isn't.` what does that mean? The shape isnt' the same? Or are the values different? Or both?

Comment: @SoufianeTahiri Thanks a lot, I just changed "buffer.Clear()" to "buffer = new new Dictionary<string, double>()" and it works perfectly. I mark Matt's answer as the answer as you answered in comment but you're the one who gave solution first.

Comment: @MatthieuFoltzer Thank you, happy I could help and never mind we're not competing we're around just to get helped and give help if we can :)

Comment: Bleep-bloop is correct; you are making way too much work for yourself.  Consider instead making a single dictionary of type `Dictionary<(string, string), double>` and skipping all this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your last `else` clause:

```
else
{
    buffer.Clear();
    buffer.Add(name, quantity);
    listeRef[reference] = buffer;                            
}
```

What you are doing here is clearing your `buffer` and then adding a new value and then adding it to `listeRef` (which I'm assuming is a typo and is supposed to be `firstDictionary`). But what you are doing here is adding *the same* dictionary for every value of `reference`. When you assign it to `firstDictionary` you aren't making a copy, you are storing a reference. And when you clear the `buffer` you are clearing the object that every entry in `firstDictionary` is pointing to. That's why you see the same value (presumably the last one processed) in every key.

So let's say you start with an empty `firstDictionary` and the first value is `foo`, `bar`, `10` - you end up with a `firstDictionary` that might look something like this:

```
{
    "foo" : {
        "bar": 10
    }
}
```

Now the next value is `la`, `far`, `12`. What happen is you clear `buffer`, and you end up with:

```
{
    "foo": {}
}
```

Then you add the new value to `buffer` and you get:

```
{
    "foo" : {
        "far": 12
    }
}
```

and then you add you "new" (but it's actually the same) dictionary under the new key to `firstDictonary`:

```
{
    "foo" : {
        "far": 12
    },
    "la": {
        "far": 12
    }
}
```

You need to create a *new* dictionary in that else clause:

```
firstDictionary[reference] = new Dictionary<string,double>() { { name, quantity }};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, it's works perfectly. I looks a bit like something I already tried before, I'm glad I wasn't that far. Thanks too to Soufiane Tahiri who gave a similar answer in comments.